# Map incremental values inside an array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to map incremental values inside an array for to select and change all of them at once

```
state.formData[0].EndDate = nextDayIfSelected
state.formData[1].EndDate = nextDayIfSelected
state.formData[2].EndDate = nextDayIfSelected
...etc
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on how the incoming data looks and what your desired output is?

Comment: for what do you need the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `state.formData` has the signature `Array<{EndDate: any}>` and `nextDayIfSelected` sharing the same type as `EndDate`, you can iterate over the array with [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
state.formData.forEach((data) => {
  data.EndDate = nextDayIfSelected;
});
```